# One way 12 V flow, diodes are blowing up

Tags: diodes, relay, dc, switching

I am trying to control a relay which pulls 142 mA when 12 VDC is supplied to either of the two legs that can close the coil. They can't back-feed the other leg (as described in the attached image).

I have been using switching diodes for this application. They are rated 1 A at 12 V. They blow up after about 3 minutes of use.

Is there a more sensible way to do this? I don't want to use another magnetic or solid state relay. They are too large and expensive. Am I using the wrong diodes?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFYvZH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Please draw a circuit with the tool, also draw the relay and voltage sources. Edit the question and use the circuit tool

Comment: What is the part number of the diodes you are using?

Comment: I made the requested edits for (Voltage Spike) and added diode PN for (Peter Bennett). Thx guys

Comment: 1N4148 is only rated about 100 mA continuous. Use something like a 1N4001 for 1 A. You also need a commutating (flyback) diode across the relay coil to protect against inductive spike at turn-off.

Comment: Which diodes are you using exactly (which model)?

Comment: How high is the coil resistance ? 85 Ohm? Do both diodes fail or only one of them? D1 or D2?

Comment: Coil resistance is 75 ohms. I calculated my allowable diode capacity in VA... That must not be OK to do. I am pretty close to their limit of 200mA if I'm pulling 142mA steady state. I will swap to a 1N4001 as PStechPaul suggested.

Comment: I don't know which diode fails actually. I will start to track that. (for Edin)

Comment: @JoeatRogueFab The current is most likely the reason for their failure. The voltage/current spike at turn-off happens in their forward direction, which means it's not the high reverse voltage spike that's destroying them. You definitely need a higher current model like 1N4001.

Comment: What is a flyback diode? I would be happy to add one. What direction do I install it? Have a recommendation for a diode? I have a few different rectifier diodes and some fast recovery and schottky ones as well. If oversizing the 2 diodes already in use will eliminate the need for a 3rd diode, that might be cheaper/easier to execute and maintain.

Comment: It's a fast diode put in antiparallel with the coil. It will recirculate the current in the coil when you switch it. You definitely need one.

Comment: Not what you asked about, but if you use Schottky diodes instead of regular silicon ones, they will run a little bit cooler and drop a little bit less voltage. Drawback is back-flow will be in the high uA range instead of high-nA-to-low-uA range.

Comment: We will add the flyback diode. Thank you all for the wonderful help. I will also be using flyback diodes whenever I use diodes for this application (with coils or other inductors) in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the schematic with the flyback diode added.

[image]

1N4001 would be the right choice for the diodes.